# Storing arguments in a variadic template function without using boost::any

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have written the following short code in C++11 of a variable template function and store the arguments into a vector of type boost::any. It is working perfectly, but I don't want to use the boost::any library (due to some limitation).

```
#include <boost/any.hpp>

template <class Var, class... Args>
void cpp_for(Var *variable, uint32_t numParams, Args... args)
{
    std::vector<boost::any> arguments{args...};

    if(arguments.size() != numParams)
        throw std::runtime_error("mismatch");

    for(uint32_t i = 0; i < numParams; ++i)
        variable[i] = *(boost::unsafe_any_cast<Var>(&arguments[i]));
}
```

And I call the function like this:

```
cpp_for(myObj->var, 3, 0x56, 0x23, 0x10);
```

Or

```
cpp_for(myObj2->var, 2, myObj2->var2, myObj2->var3);
```

Is there any way to store the arguments and process them one by one without the need for boost::any?

Edit 1: my arguments are all of the same type.

Edit 2: Since the goal of the code above is `assignment`, then creating an extra data structure (vector) is useless. Check 'Nir Friedman''s answer for a more efficient solution.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting the type of passed argument in variadic function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3564061/getting-the-type-of-passed-argument-in-variadic-function)

Comment: It is pretty totally unclear what this function is actually trying to accomplish. Like, why bother creating a vector at all? Why are you specifying the number of parameters by hand?

Comment: I think the `sizeof...` operator may help you

Comment: Using a function name of all caps confuses it with preprocessor functions.

Comment: @CodeLurker: Initially I was looking for a replacement for P99_FOR in C++11 and CPP_FOR is an attempt to replicate it (somehow), but I forgot to change the name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [`std::common_type`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_type), e.g.:

```
template <class Var, class... Args>
void CPP_FOR(Var *variable, uint32_t numParams, Args... args)
{
    std::vector<std::common_type_t<Args...>> arguments{args...};
    // do stuff with arguments
}
```

You can also remove `numParams` and the runtime check because this will fail at compile time if there is no common type. And if you only want to iterate over the arguments, a vector is maybe overkill... so something like:

```
template <class Var, class... Args>
void CPP_FOR(Var *variable, Args... args)
{
    std::common_type_t<Args...> arguments[]{args...};
    for(size_t i = 0; i < sizeof...(Args); ++i)
        variable[i] = /* ... */;
}
```

Note that both of these will fails if `sizeof... (Args)` is 0, i.e. you are calling with only a `Var*` - You may want to handle this case separately if necessary.

Comment: This is probably a better approach than my answer (was not aware of `std::common_type`). I suggest adding a note about the case where `sizeof...(Args)` is zero.

Comment: If the goal is assignment, then creating any kind of data structure from the arguments is needless and inefficient. you can just assign them directly as in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming that your goal is really just to perform assignments, you don't need a vector at all.

```
template <class Var, class... Args>
void CPP_FOR(Var *variable, uint32_t numParams, Args... args)
{    
    if(sizeof...(Args) != numParams)
        throw std::runtime_error("mismatch");

    int i = 0;
    int temp [] = {(variable[i++] = args, 0)...};
}
```

Live example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/710a09332bf2c965

Not only is this zero overhead compared to creating a vector that is hard to optimize away, but it will allow implicit conversions in the most natural way. Other approaches may have surprises.

Comment: Is there a guarantee regarding the evaluation order of the `i++` in this pack expansion?

Comment: Packs have to be expanded left to right, if that's what you are asking.

Comment: Expanded, yes. But evaluated, no. I don't think the order is well-defined. Have you tried running this?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo evaluated too. You are getting confused with function argument evaluation order. Brace packs have to be evaluated left to right. I provide a live link right in my answer...

Comment: @Holt E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14060264/order-of-evaluation-of-elements-in-list-initialization

Comment: I think we can remove the 'numParams' check altogether, too. You beat me to the array expansion! And it's simpler. [I used an index sequence](https://wandbox.org/permlink/wuH6so8nmshLbiUW), which I thought was nice, but those weren't standardized until C++14, either.

Comment: @AndyG Yeah, the annoying thing with index sequences is that they always require calling out to another function. This trick is nice for quick and dirty solutions. Though, IMHO the real way to go is to have a small library can apply variadic lambdas to tuples/packs, and conceal this array trick/integer sequence behind that. You can have a version that passes in the integer to the lambda as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you know that there's going to be at least one argument, you can write your function slightly differently to do so.

```
template <typename Arg, typename... Args>
void cpp_for(Arg arg, Args... args) {
  std::vector<Arg> vec { arg, args... };
  // ...
}
```

However, this will fail if the argument list is empty. The easiest solution to this is simply to add a second overload of `cpp_for` which takes no arguments.

```
void cpp_for() {
  std::vector<SomeDefaultType> vec; // Empty vector
  // ...
}
```

Of course, you only need to do so if it makes sense to call your function with zero arguments.

Bear in mind that this approach will give positively miserable error messages if `Args` and `Arg` don't all end up being the same type. This can be remedied with some careful use of `static_assert`.